# How to set up a custom logger filter in django

Tags: django, logging

I am trying to set up a custom log filter in django, but I am stuck with an error:

```
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'user_filter': 'module' object has no attribute 'Filter'
```

I get this error when I try to run the django development server.

The purpose of this is to log name of the user, which is a request variable defined in my middleware.

Here is what I have in my `settigs.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(user)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'user_filter': {
            '()': 'creative.logging.UserFilter',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': BASE_DIR+'/logs/default.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
        'request_handler': {
                'level':'DEBUG',
                'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': BASE_DIR+'/logs/django_request.log',
                'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
                'backupCount': 5,
                'formatter':'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'format':'%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(funcName)s |%(message)s',
            'propagate': False,
            'filters': ['user_filter']
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['request_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}
```

and in `creative/logging.py`:

```
import logging

class UserFilter(logging.Filter):
     def filter(self, record):
         record.user = record.request.user_profie['fullName']
         return True
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just do not name the module `logging.py`.

Comment: renamed it to customlogging, and changed in settings.py, I still get the same error

Comment: Make sure `logging.pyc` is not there.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use the similar code by adding it in django settings file. But I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'LogRecord' object has no attribute 'request' `. Any guess what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As said in the comments, you named your file `logging.py` so it overrides the default module chosen by `import logging`.